# Change value of cell within named range of certain row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, but as soon as the first len 3 shows up in `RefNbr`, it changes the entire range of `Manitoba` to zero. How do I make it so it only changes the line/row it is referencing at that time?

```
Dim wsMonthly As Worksheet
Dim nmbrRowsMonthly As Integer

Set wsMonthly = Sheets(1)
nmbrRowsMonthly = wsMonthly.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Name range
Set rngManitoba = wsMonthly.Range("L2:L" & nmbrRowsMonthly)
Sheets(1).Names.Add Name:="Manitoba", RefersTo:=rngManitoba

Sheets(1).Activate
Dim RefNbr As Range
Dim x As Range
Set RefNbr = Range("B2", Range("B1000").End(xlUp))

For Each x In RefNbr
    If Len(x.Value) = 3 Then
        Range("Manitoba").Value = 0
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: `x.Value = 0`??

Comment: @BigBen -manitoba is `L` and RefNbr is `B`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - crap I didn't read.

Comment: @BigBen - happens to the best and worst of us (hahahaha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim wsMonthly As Worksheet
Set wsMonthly = Sheets(1)

With wsMonthly 

    Dim nmbrRowsMonthly As Long
    nmbrRowsMonthly = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'Name range
    Set rngManitoba = .Range("L2:L" & nmbrRowsMonthly)
    .Names.Add Name:="Manitoba", RefersTo:=rngManitoba

    Dim RefNbr As Range
    Dim x As Range
    Set RefNbr = Range("B2:B" & nmbrRowsMonthly)

    For Each x In RefNbr
        If Len(x.Value) = 3 Then
            Range("Manitoba").Cells(x.Row,1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next x

End With
```